# Docker - which version supports the trust command?

Tags: docker

We would like to enable docker trust (image signing) in our environment. From which version the docker the [trust](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/trust/) command is supported?

Now we have RHEL 7 with docker 1.13.1 (bundled by default). This version doesn't support any trust command. Or do we need Docker Enterprise version for the trust feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker trust` command line is available in the current stable version of the docker CE CLI. You'll need to install from Docker's repos directly rather than RedHat's stale fork. The CentOS instructions have worked for me on RHEL:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/

Here are the logs from a Debian install:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:36:00 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       481bc77
  Built:            Sat May  4 01:59:36 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

$ docker trust --help

Usage:  docker trust COMMAND

Manage trust on Docker images

Management Commands:
  key         Manage keys for signing Docker images
  signer      Manage entities who can sign Docker images

Commands:
  inspect     Return low-level information about keys and signatures
  revoke      Remove trust for an image
  sign        Sign an image

Run 'docker trust COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```